# OAuth2WebServerFlow works from localhost, but not from real AppEngine Instance

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gdata

I'm using OAuth2WebServerFlow to get the User's Sheets credentials to use with the gdata/spreadsheets API. I'm having a really hard time diagnosing the problem because it works flawlessly when I run the application locally.

This is the snippet I'm using to get the authorization URL:

```
CLIENT_ID = 'my-id'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'my-secret'
SCOPE = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'
flow_object = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPE, redirect_uri=self.REDIRECT_URL, access_type='online')
authorize_url = flow_object.step1_get_authorize_url()
```

Locally (using `REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/this-path/'`)
this produces:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fthis-path%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fspreadsheets.google.com%2Ffeeds&client_id=my-id&response_type=code&access_type=online`

On the live App Engine application (using `REDIRECT_URL = 'http://my-app.appspot.com/this-path/'`)
this produces:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fspreadsheets.google.com%2Ffeeds&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-app.appspot.com%2Fthis-path%2F&response_type=code&client_id=my-id&access_type=online`

The application configuration looks like:

```
CLIENT ID: my-id
EMAIL ADDRESS: my-id@developer.gserviceaccount.com
CLIENT SECRET:  my-secret
REDIRECT URIS:
    http://localhost:8080/
    http://my-app.appspot.com
    https://my-app.appspot.com
    http://my-app.appspot.com/this-path
    https://my-app.appspot.com/this-path
    http://my-app.appspot.com/this-path/
    https://my-app.appspot.com/this-path/
JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS
    http://localhost:8080
    http://my-app.appspot.com
```

Going to the locally generated version of the url I can successfully grant the application permission. But at the url generated by my live application I get a 401 that says "Error: disabled_client The OAuth client was disabled".

I feel like its probably just a configuration error. Maybe the fact that it works locally is just a red herring? Perhaps I would always be able to grant localhost these permissions? I'm genuinely out of ideas on this and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the application configuration, redirect URL should be like this http://localhost:8080/**oauth2callback**, as according to my understanding **oauth2callback** authorizes the token at the end of the flow. Refer to the document [1].

[1] **OAUTH 2.0**: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#OAuth2WebServerFlow

Comment: So I understand correctly, are you saying that you think the path literally has to be "oauth2callback"? I can give it a try later to see, but I'm skeptical. Especially given that "oauth2callback" isn't anywhere on the page you used as a reference.